# ansible merge 2 task with condition checks

Tags: ansible

Need help to merge below 2 tasks in 1 task. tasks are divided based on vrf value.

```
 proc_vrf: [{''proc'': ''T1'', ''vrf'': ''default''}, {''proc'': ''T2'', ''vrf'': ''vrf_T2''}, {''proc'': ''T3'', ''vrf'': ''default''}, {''proc'': ''T3'', ''vrf'': ''vrf_T3''}]
   
  - name: Shut ospf for default vrf
    cisco.nxos.nxos_command:
      commands:
      - conf t
      - router ospf {{ item.proc }}
      - shutdown
    when: item.vrf == 'default'
    with_items: "{{ proc_vrf }}"

  - name: Shut ospf for other vrf
    cisco.nxos.nxos_command:
      commands:
      - conf t
      - router ospf {{ item.proc }}
      - vrf {{ item.vrf }}
      - shutdown
    when: item.vrf != 'default'
    with_items: "{{ proc_vrf }}"
```

I fixed the commands that were being executed so you can see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `if else`:

```
- name: Shut ospf for vrf
  cisco.nxos.nxos_command:
    commands: "{{ val }}"
  with_items: "{{ proc_vrf }}"
  vars:
    valother:
      - conf t
      - router ospf {{ item.proc }}
      - vrf {{ item.vrf }}
      - shutdown
    valdefaut:
      - conf t
      - router ospf {{ item.proc }}
      - shutdown
    val: "{{ valdefaut if item.vrf|lower == 'default' else valother }}"
```

Comment: I fixed the commands that were being executed so you can see the difference. please see updated tasks. how to merge those 2 tasks in 1 task?

Comment: its not the same problem...see my answer fixed

Comment: is it possible to do this in nested loop?

Comment: you are changing your problem.. i have already answered to your second question...and i suppose its functional...but  i dont understant when you speak about nested loop....so open a new question to avoid to pollute this question